# Function syntax in event listeners

Tags: javascript, function, dom, syntax, event-listener

I'm still quite new to coding so sorry if this is a question with an obvious answer.

I'm using event listeners in JavaScript to toggle the display of a paragraph on a webpage. I can get it to work but am confused as to why certain syntax isn't valid.

If I type `moreInfoButtonCourse1.addEventListener("click", toggleDisplay(course1Info));` then nothing happens; the function doesn't work. However if I change this to

```
moreInfoButtonCourse1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  toggleDisplay(course1Info);
});
```

then it does work. Why is the first option invalid but the second is fine? Thanks!

Comment: The first is incorrect because `toggleDisplay(course1Info)` calls the function immediately and gives the result to `addEventListener`. It expects a function, rather than the function's result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in your first example you're invoking the function as it is added:

```js
moreInfoButtonCourse1.addEventListener("click", toggleDisplay(course1Info));
```

`toggleDisplay(courseInfo)` gets called as soon as you add the event listener, and it presumably returns `undefined`, which is what is getting added as a function - and so no function is called when the event is trigger.

Your other example is doing the correct thing - it's adding a function which calls `toggleDisplay(courseInfo)`.